# Splunk LDAP authentication

Tags: active-directory, ldap, splunk, splunk-formula

It seems one of the LDAP strategies has stopped working for an unknown reason.  I have confirmed the password and the settings are correct.  I have also checked the *Map Groups* field and confirmed that the *user* role has been added and I am able to see all the user that should be in there under *LDAP Users*  I have also tried reloading authentication configuration with no luck.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Below is the message I am getting.  Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated not sure where else to go from here.

> ```
> 3/11/20
>
> 8:30:46.318 AM
>
> 03-11-2020 08:30:46.318 -0500 ERROR UiAuth - user=myuser action=login
> status=failure reason=user-initiated useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows
> NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" clientip=123.123.123.123
>
> host = abc001source = \Splunk\var\log\splunk\splunkd.logsourcetype =
> splunkd
>
> 3/11/20
>
> 8:30:46.318 AM
>
> 03-11-2020 08:30:46.318 -0500 ERROR UserManagerPro - LDAP Login
> failed, could not find a valid user="myuser" on any configured servers
>
> host = abc001source = *\Splunk\var\log\splunk\splunkd.logsourcetype =
> splunkd
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Please double check your bindDNPassword for LDAP Service account and LDAP password policy.
I encountered the same error when I kept the wrong password and Service account got locked.
I had to reset the password and it worked for me. Give it a try.
Thank you.